# Use opentest with firefox behind a proxy

Tags: selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, opentest

Good morning.

I am trying to run a test case in Opentest, using firefox and the geckodriver web driver, but I need to be able to run said test using a proxy.

With the chrome browser, just indicate the --proxy-server parameter

How can I start firefox driver with opentest using a proxy?